# Problems with links using pdfpages and pax

Tags: pdfpages, html, pax

I have to merge some HTML documentation into a LaTeX workflow. I am running into problems with internal links using the `pax` package.

I am using `wkhtmltopdf` to produce the pdf pages from the html.
I use the `pdfpages` package along with `pax` to embed those pdf pages into the LaTeX source.

When I compile with pdflatex the links from the html-sourced pdf no longer work.

The links *do work* in the wkhtmltopdf-generated
pdfs before they're included in the LaTeX document.

I extract the link info using java 1.6 with this command:

```
java -cp /usr/local/share/java/pax.jar:/usr/local/share/java/PDFBox-0.7.3.jar \
pax.PDFAnnotExtractor filename.pdf
```

I've also used the `pdfannotextractor.pl` script that comes with pax, with
the same results: I get plenty of error messages like this:

```
!!! Warning: Annotation on page 1 not recognized!
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Although at the end of those warnings, it says `* Result: [ok]`
The `debug` information from the script looks like this:

```
PDFAnnotExtractor 0.1l, 2012/04/18 - Copyright (c) 2008, 2011, 2012 by Heiko Oberdiek.
* CLASSPATH: []
* is_win: [0]
* pax.jar: [/usr/local/share/java/pax.jar]
* pdfbox.jar: [/usr/local/share/java/PDFBox-0.7.3.jar]
* Which java: [/usr/local/bin/java]
* System: [java -cp /usr/local/share/java/pax.jar:/usr/local/share/java/PDFBox-0.7.3.jar pax.PDFAnnotExtractor logistic_python.pdf]
```

If I turn off internal links with wkhtmltopdf, I get no errors.

The pax file is still created but it looks non-informative--lines look like this:

```
\[{pagenum}{18}\\
\[{page}{1}{0 0 612 792}{}\\
\[{annot}{1}{Link}{50.82 579.93 75.57 591.18}{GoTo}{
  DestLabel={1},
  Border={[0 0 0]},
}\\
```

And sure enough, when I pdflatex the LaTeX document,
the links in the in the generated PDF do not work.

I'm on FreeBSD, using TeXLive 2015, PDFBox-0.7.3.
I create the pdfs from html on a Windows machine with the latest wkhtmltopdf.

*edit*

Thinking the difference between platforms might be the cause, I tried using the `pax` java program on windows as well as the `wkhtmltopdf` program (Win7). Same results. Also I am now using this simple html file for testing:

```
<html>
<head><title>my title</title></head>
<body>
  <h1>test</h1>
  <p><a href="#myanchor">Click</a> me.</p>
  <h2><a name="myanchor">Anchor</a></h4>
  <p>text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the null pointer exception even with this simple case.

```
wkhtmltopdf test.htm test.pdf
java -cp path\to\pax.jar;\path\to\pdfbox.jar test.pdf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is not a problem with the `pax` package or its corresponding java program. The PDF that `wkhtmltopdf` creates has a non-standard structure (whatever standard really means when it comes to PDF).

I wrote a very specific python program to parse such PDFs and write out a `pax` file after the style of the `pax` package's java program. It works for me and I can "include" html files in my LaTeX workflow.

1. convert the html+css to pdf using wkhtmltopdf
2. use my python program to write out the `pax` file
3. use the `pdfpages` and `pax` packages to create the final pdf with LaTeX.

Result is the included PDF looks good (wkhtmltopdf understands css) and the links work. The `pax` package is awesome.

If anyone else comes across this problem, please see my github repo with the code:

https://github.com/tiarno/paxmaker